# Font Awsome icons not showing when I add them using javascript

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

I'm trying to use `Font Awsome` in my web poject,
I've added the link:

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/bedf006dec.js"></script>
```

When I add font awesome directly to my `HTML` like this:

```
<div class="topbar">
       <div class="topbar__elements container">
           <div class="topbar__left">
               <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <span> Middle East Airlines Ground Handling</span>
               </a>
               <a href="mailto:meag@meag.com.lb" target="_top" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                   <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                   <span> meag@meag.com.lb</span>
               </a>
               <a href="tel:00961 1 622700">
                   <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                   <span> +961 1 622700</span>
               </a>
           </div>
           <div class="topbar__right">
               <a href="#">Career</a>
               <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

It works fine:
[image]

I'm also using [tiny slider](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider) and I want to change the text of the `previous` and `next` buttons to have `Font Awsome` icons, I know that I can create custom buttons with tiny slider directly in the HTML code but I'm trying to use the default controls of tiny slider, therefore to try and change the text of these 2 buttons I'm using `javascript`:

```
const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".tns-controls").firstChild;
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".tns-controls").lastChild;

prevBtn.innerHTML = "<i class='fa-solid fa-angle-left' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
nextBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
```

But it doesn't work and give me this:
[image]

Even though when I open the developer tools it looks like as if it worked.

Comment: can you include the `html` which has the `.tns-controls`?

Comment: @tenshi ```.tns-controls``` is the default controls of the ```tns slider``` it is not something that I write in my ```html```